# How to work with functions inside the same react component?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function PhoneBookForm({ addEntryToPhoneBook }) {
  const state = {
    userFirstname: "Coder",
    userLastname: "Byte",
    userPhone: "8885559999",
  };
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <label>First name:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        className="userFirstname"
        name="userFirstname"
        type="text"
        value={state.userFirstname}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Last name:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        className="userLastname"
        name="userLastname"
        type="text"
        value={state.userLastname}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Phone:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        className="userPhone"
        name="userPhone"
        type="text"
        value={state.userPhone}
      />
      <br />
      <input className="submitButton" type="submit" value="Add User" />
    </form>
  );
}

function InformationTable(props) {
  return (
    <table className="informationTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  );
}

function Application(props) {
  return (
    <section>
      <PhoneBookForm />
      <InformationTable />
    </section>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When this application loads, the input fields (not the phone book list) should be prepopulated with the following values already:

```
First name = Coder  
Last name = Byte  
Phone = 8885559999
```

How to do this? How do I display the input values to the table?
I added a  tag with 3  tags for each state const property, but I do not know how to relate them to it from the InformationTable function.

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    userFirstname: "Coder",
    userLastname: "Byte",
    userPhone: "8885559999",
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.formSubmitted}>
          <label>First name:</label>
          <br/>
          <input className="userFirstname" name="userFirstname" type="text" value={this.state.userFirstname} onChange={this.inputOnChange}/>
          <br/>
          <label>Last name:</label>
          <br/>
          <input className="userLastname" name="userLastname" type="text" value={this.state.userLastname} onChange={this.inputOnChange}/>
          <br/>
          <label>Phone:</label>
          <br/>
          <input className="userPhone" name="userPhone" type="text" value={this.state.userPhone} onChange={this.inputOnChange}/>
          <br/>
          <input className="submitButton" type="submit" value="Add User"/>
        </form>

        <InformationTable users={this.state.users}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };


  formSubmitted = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const users = this.state.users;

    const newUser = {
      userFirstname: this.state.userFirstname,
      userLastname: this.state.userLastname,
      userPhone: this.state.userPhone,
    };

    users.push(newUser);

    this.setState({users: users});
  }

  inputOnChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }
}

function InformationTable(props) {
  return (
    <table className="informationTable">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
      {
        props.users.map((user, index) => {
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{user.userFirstname}</td>
              <td>{user.userLastname}</td>
              <td>{user.userPhone}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      }
      </thead>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I hate using functions, this is what you want, if you have any questions I'm free to help.

Comment: Thank you, yeah, the thing is that for this challenge I should use the code as it is. I can add classes, but I should follow the functions approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to connect two React components with a common state, you should hoist that state to their common parent component. That means that the state of input will be declared in `Application` function-component and passed to child components as props. These are the fundamentals of React and this info is brilliantly written in React doc. Also check the `useState` hook in [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), the way you create the state in `PhoneBookForm` is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly copy this code in index.js file & run your project

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const style = {
  table: {
    borderCollapse: "collapse"
  },
  tableCell: {
    border: "1px solid gray",
    margin: 0,
    padding: "5px 10px",
    width: "max-content",
    minWidth: "150px"
  },
  form: {
    container: {
      padding: "20px",
      border: "1px solid #F0F8FF",
      borderRadius: "15px",
      width: "max-content",
      marginBottom: "40px"
    },
    inputs: {
      marginBottom: "5px"
    },
    submitBtn: {
      marginTop: "10px",
      padding: "10px 15px",
      border: "none",
      backgroundColor: "lightseagreen",
      fontSize: "14px",
      borderRadius: "5px"
    }
  }
};

function PhoneBookForm({ addEntryToPhoneBook }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  function handleChange({ target: { name, value } }) {
    setUser(prevUser => ({ ...prevUser, [name]: value }));
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addEntryToPhoneBook(user);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={style.form.container}>
      <label>First name:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        style={style.form.inputs}
        className="userFirstname"
        name="userFirstname"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Last name:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        style={style.form.inputs}
        className="userLastname"
        name="userLastname"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Phone:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        style={style.form.inputs}
        className="userPhone"
        name="userPhone"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        style={style.form.submitBtn}
        className="submitButton"
        type="submit"
        value="Add User"
      />
    </form>
  );
}

function InformationTable({ users }) {
  return (
    <table style={style.table} className="informationTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>First name</th>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>Last name</th>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {users.map(user => (
        <tr>
          <td>user.userFirstname</td>
          <td>user.userLastname</td>
          <td>user.userPhone</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

function Application(props) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  function handleNewEntry(user) {
    setUsers(prevUsers => [...prevUsers, user]);
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <PhoneBookForm addEntryToPhoneBook={handleNewEntry} />
      <InformationTable users={users} />
    </section>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```